# Spring ReflectionTestUtils does not set primitive data type field

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I use ReflectionTestUtils to set int field in my service class to test the class.
My service class like:

```
@Service
public class SampleService {

    @Value("${app.count}")
    private int count;

    @Value("${app.countStr}")
    private String countStr;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getCountStr() {
        return countStr;
    }

    public void setCountStr(String countStr) {
        this.countStr = countStr;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public int demoMethod() {
        return count + Integer.parseInt(countStr);
    }
}
```

and test class is like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SampleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class SampleServiceTestConfig {

        @Bean
        public SampleService sampleService() {
            return new SampleService();
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(sampleService, "count", new Integer(100));
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(sampleService, "countStr", 100);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDemoMethod() {
        int a  = sampleService.demoMethod();
        Assert.assertTrue(a == 200);
    }
}
```

While I run this test case it gives below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${app.count}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:210)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:70)
    ... 47 more
```

Why ReflectionTestUtils try set string value in the field?

I put 2 fields, one is an integer and another is a string for testing purpose.

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/nitinvavdiya/junit-test-for-property).

Please have look and suggest a workaround for the same.

Comment: If you change the type of  `count` to String then it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While testing, you have to provide properties source. If you don't add properties, it will inject the value inside `@Value` in the variable. In your case, it tries to add the string in the integer that gives `NumberFormatException`.
Try adding as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"app.count=1", "app.countStr=sampleString"})
public class SampleServiceTest{...}
```

As you are using `@Autowired`, before `ReflectionTestUtils` it tries to add the value inside `@Value`.

Comment: This is a workaround for the issue.`ReflectionTestUtils.setField` has an object type of argument, then it should not inject string.

Comment: It is not injecting anything at all. The error will be caused before that code comes in the picture, Mate.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the method annotated with `@Before` is invoked **after** that the spring context was initialized and that the service was injected by Spring in your test class.
Which means that these two fields :

```
@Value("${app.count}")
private int count;

@Value("${app.countStr}")
private String countStr;
```

will have as value the value defined in their `@Value` values.
`String countStr` can be valued with the `"${app.countStr}"`  `String` (even it it makes no sense).
But `int count` cannot be valued with  the `"${app.count}"`  `String` as **`"${app.count}"` cannot be converted into an int value**.
Whereas the thrown exception as `Integer.parseInt("${app.count}")` is invoked :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${app.count}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
```

To address this issue, use `@TestPropertySource` as suggested by Nisheeth Shah to  provide the value for the properties at the suitable time.

As a general advise, limit the reflection use. It is checked only at runtime and that is often more opaque.

Comment: Modifying bean definition is not working.It throws the same error.The approach suggested by Nisheeth is working.I modified bean definition in GitHub, you can check it is not working.

Comment: @Nitin Vavdiya Sure that the `@TestPropertySource` approach is working. For making the other approach working you should specify a default null value for the `@Value`. It makes the solution more complex and besides  the bean defined in `TestConfiguration` is probably not required I think. You should probably remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Also in addition, make sure you don't redefine the variables like below in test class.

```
@Value("${app.count}")
private int count;
@Value("${app.countStr}")
private String countStr;
```

Many times due to copy pasting variables from target class leads to such mistakes.

And for original problem asked, this simple straightforward solution below also works.

```
@Before
    public void init() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(sampleService, "count", 100);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(sampleService, "countStr", "100");
    }
```